# LinqPad4 - Can I execute action of odata with parameters in linqpad?

Tags: odata, linqpad

I connected to the service and ran selects.
I saw that I can insert object but I didn't find a way to run action on ODATA.

Here for example an action that I have:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public void SendAuxiliary([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you mean by action?

Comment: just edit it into your question please with a complete description of what you are tryingin to do and what/why it isnt working